# how to start a global thread in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, swift

Is there any way to start and stop a thread in swift along with it making the thread global also so that it can used anywhere.

As shown below, this is how i create thread in swift

```
var objThrd = SimpleClass()
let thread = NSThread(target: objThrd , selector: "createSimpleObj", object: nil)
```

Please give an example if feasible. Or can we achieve this via NSOperation ?

Comment: Have you looked at Grand Central Dispatch? It is considered to be the preferred method of dealing with concurrency and threading these days. It works with queues, not threads, but you should really take a look at it. See this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/

Comment: If you clarify your question, we might be able to answer your question better. What are you really trying to do? It looks like you want to call the method `objThrd.createSimpleObj()` on a background queue. If that is the case, the @Max's answer below is spot-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Grand Central Dispatch

```
    let myQueue: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.queue", nil)
    dispatch_async(myQueue, { () -> Void in
        // Execute some code
    })
```

Comment: You don't need to start and stop it. Just call the dispatch method any time you want to do "createSimpleObject"

Answer (score 0):

I use a small function, which uses Central Dispatch, to start a new thread:

```
typealias FuncPointer = () -> () // Pointer to a function

func startprocess (_ f: FuncPointer)
{
    let atrb = DispatchQueue.GlobalAttributes.qosUserInteractive
    DispatchQueue.global(attributes: atrb).async(group: DispatchGroup())
    {
        f()
    }
}
```

To start a function as a thread, you call it like:

```
startprocess(myFuncName)
```

The function "myFuncName" is a function without parameters and without a result. This example works in Swift 3.0 beta 3 and Xcode 8 beta 3. You can start multiple threads after each other without waiting for something.

You can use the following function:

```
_ = group.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
```

To wait, until all threads of a specific group have finished. So you start the threads not with DispatchGroup(), but with a predefined group variable. This is an easy way to handle a group of more than 1 threads. Example for six threads:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
let myThreadCount: Int = 6
for _ in 1...myThreadCount
{
    DispatchQueue.global(attributes: DispatchQueue.GlobalAttributes.qosUserInteractive).async(group: group)
    {
        Calculate(NumberOfSteps / ThreadCurrentCount)
    }
}
_ = group.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
```